# Use Map function with the base R pipe |>

Tags: r, higher-order-functions, map-function

How can I use the `Map` function with the pipe base `|>`?

The next `x` vector can be used inside the `Map` function

```
x <- c(1,5,1,2)
Map(function(n)n*2, x) |> unlist()
# [1]  2 10  2  4
```

This works, but when I try to use the pipe I get the next error:

```
x |> Map(function(n)n*2, ...= _)
#Error in (function (n)  : unused argument (... = dots[[1]][[1]])
```

So I make another anonymous function, but it is difficult to read

```
x |> (function(x) Map(function(n)n*2,x))() |> unlist()
#[1]  2 10  2  4
```

I would like to know why the `Map` can't take the *place holder* `_`.

#### Another solution

I change the order of the arguments of `Map` so It can be more legible

```
myMap <- \(...,f) Map(f, ...)
x |> myMap(f = function(n)n*2) |> unlist()
#[1]  2 10  2  4
```

Comment: What is the reason to use `Map`? In this case there is no need for it as `x |> (\(n) n*2)()` or `x*2` will already work.

Comment: It was just to exemplify the problem. You're right, there's no need to use a `Map` as vectorization is more efficient. Actually, i was using a list in a pipe flow. Something like this `l |> Filter |> Map |> Reduce`. `Map` does not accept the place holder as `Filter` and `Reduce`, and I couldn't understand why

Comment: So do the Answers help to solve this?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I will edit the question to add your contributions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to name the function so the first free position is used by the pipe.

```
x |> Map(f=function(n)n*2) |> unlist()
#[1]  2 10  2  4
```

But `Map` or `mapply` typical are used for *multiple* arguments and here either the position or the given name matters. The placeholder `_` currently (R 4.3.0) needs named argument, also for functions which have only `...` but here any free name could be used.

```
 1:3 |> mapply(`paste`, 1, .=_)
#[1] "1 1" "1 2" "1 3"

1:3 |> mapply(`paste`, .=_, 1)
#[1] "1 1" "2 1" "3 1"

1:3 |> mapply(`paste`, x=_, 1)
#[1] "1 1" "2 1" "3 1"
```

In case the function uses the names, the same names need to be used as an argument for `Map` or `mapply`.

```
1:3 |> Map(seq, 1, to=_)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 2 3

1:3 |> Map(seq, 1, from=_)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 1
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
x |> Map(function(n) n * 2, n = _) |> unlist()
```

The reason is that `Map` is basically `mapply`

> mapply calls FUN for the values of ... (re-cycled to the length of the longest, unless any have length zero where recycling to zero length will return list()), followed by the arguments given in MoreArgs. **The arguments in the call will be named if ... or MoreArgs are named**.

So, your function has a named argument `n`, therefore, you can pipe into that argument.